# Windows Server 2012 r2 + XAMPP + SqlSrv = unsuccessful so far

Tags: php, sql-server, configuration, xampp, sqlsrv

I have a Windows 2012 R2 server with XAMPP installed. I need to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database but I saw the mssql-library is no longer supported and I was redirected to the [official Microsoft package SqlSrv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx).

I've unzipped all files to `d:\xampp\php\ext` and I've added `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll` in my php.ini.

Using XAMPP's controlpanel I've restarted Apache but it didn't work. I'm always getting the errors:

```
[20-Apr-2015 08:38:08 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[20-Apr-2015 08:38:08 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0
```

I've checked a few times to be sure the filename is correct. The file truely exists. All system users have full control over the file (any file in the \ext directory for that matter). It also doesn't matter to switch to a `ts` or `non-pdo` variant.

I'm running PHP 5.6.3. Any suggestions? I'm out of ideas to look for the issue...

**Update 1:** 
Via several form posts I came across a C++ Redistributable to install, so I've got that covered. But still I'm missing out on some DLL's according do depends.exe (Dependency Walker).

To this point I'm missing the following DLL's:

- API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
- PHP5.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHUTDOWN-L1-1-1.DLL
- EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-UICONTEXT-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
- IESHIMS.DLL
- SETTINGSYNCPOLICY.DLL
- WLANAPI.DLL

I assume they're part of a package I'm missing. I also saw some posts about installing the latest SQL Server Native Client. But as far as I found the latest version is 11, but is too old for Windows 2012R2.

**Update 2:**
On [this forum page](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=70553&p=241917#p241917) I saw a useful reaction (in German) telling SqlSrv can't work with the latest available XAMPP PHP version. So I've reinstalled XAMPP with PHP 5.5.19 now, but this still didn't help.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've found out what's wrong.

At this moment I'm succesfully running SqlSrv on my Windows 2012R2 machine with XAMPP. The main problem was I was using the `*nts.dll` files. Using Dependency Walker I was able to get a list of dll's that were not loaded succesfully. One of the DLL's listed there was `php5.dll`. It took me a while to figure out that would be strange. I've inspectected my php folder and I saw the file `php5ts.dll` in there, but no `php5.dll` So I Googled for `sqlsrv php5.dll` and I came across [this page from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170(v=sql.105).aspx).

That page lists which drivers work with which DLL for PHP. I've switched the modules from `nts` to `ts` and now everything is working as expected. At this moment I've also installed the C++ redistributable to fix the MSVCP110.dll issue but I'm not sure if that was mandatory to get it working. If you run into the same issue maybe you'll also have to install this patch ([Microsoft downloadpage](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679), I've downloaded `VSU_4\vcredist_x86.exe`)

Good luck future solution seekers!